Confused by this usage of って
The character is attempting to steal a thing and as he reaches for the item he exclaims:
人のものって燃えるわ!
Obviously I don't think he's saying "people's things burn" so what exactly is he going on? I take it's "fire me up" but why is って used?


This type of って is a colloquial version of とは, which is used to explain a definition or an important characteristic of something. For example, you can say "それって?" ("What does it mean?").
What is "burning" here is not someone else's belongings, but the speaker's own emotions. In other words, it's one of the ways to say "exciting".


人のものって燃えるわ!
(Stealing) other people's things is thrilling!

